# NULL fields using PIVOT

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot

I request your collaboration because `pivot` on a table and separating the records by `null`, but still leave the fields at 0 with `NVL`

Table

```
product   | value
----------+-------
Shirts    | 1200
Caps      | 0
Stocks    | 0
Glasses   | 100
Shoes     | 0
```

Código pivot

```
select * from products
 PIVOT (sum(value)
   for titles in ('product', 'value')) AS pivot_product
```

Result:

```
 product  |  Shirts   |  Caps  |    Stocks   | Glasses | Shoes
 ---------+-----------+--------+-------------+---------+----------
   value  |    NULL   |  NULL  |    NULL     |   100   |   NULL
   value  |    1200   |  NULL  |    NULL     |   NULL  |   NULL
```

Expected result:

```
 product  |  Shirts   |  Caps  |    Stocks   | Glasses | Shoes
 ---------+-----------+--------+-------------+-------+----------
   valor  |    1200   |  NULL  |    NULL     |  100  |   NULL
```

Optional

```
 product  |  Shirts   |  Caps  |    Stocks   | Glasses | Shoes
 ---------+-----------+--------+-------------+-------+----------
   valor  |    1200   |    0   |      0      |  100  |    0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the column values in the pivot list:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( product, value ) AS
SELECT 'Shirts', 1200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Caps',      0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Stocks',    0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Glasses', 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Shoes',     0 FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT 'value' AS product,
       p.*
FROM   test_data
PIVOT ( SUM( value ) FOR product IN (
  'Shirts'  AS Shirts,
  'Caps'    AS Caps,
  'Stocks'  AS Stocks,
  'Glasses' AS Glasses,
  'Shoes'   AS Shoes
) ) p
```

**Output**:

```
PRODUCT | SHIRTS | CAPS | STOCKS | GLASSES | SHOES
:------ | -----: | ---: | -----: | ------: | ----:
value   |   1200 |    0 |      0 |     100 |     0
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8e8f7c64587111af136f8f5ebc0c732b)*

Comment: Is there a possibility that the columns are dynamic and not manual?

Answer (score 2):

Just use conditional aggregation.  It is more flexible:

```
select 'valor' as product,
       sum(case when product = 'Shirts' then value end) as shirts,
       sum(case when product = 'Caps' then value end) as caps,
       sum(case when product = 'Stocks' then value end) as stockes,
       sum(case when product = 'Shirts' then value end) as shirts,
       sum(case when product = 'Glasses' then value end) as glasses,
       sum(case when product = 'Shoes' then value end) as shoes
from test_data;
```